# Foundation select menu width

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with Foundation select menu, I found some results on google but nothing seems to work.

I'm using:

```
<label>Select Menu
  <select>
    <option value="husker">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin risus. Praesent lectus.</option>
    <option value="starbuck">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin risus. Praesent lectus.</option>
    <option value="hotdog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin risus. Praesent lectus.</option>
    <option value="apollo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin risus. Praesent lectus.</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

I tried to set in the css Foundation the width options for select and for the options:

```
select {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  border-radius: 0; }

select option {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

And the result is still wrong, it is somehow taking the maxim possible width of the text.

This is the resut:
[image]

Comment: As far I Know, it is not possible using `select`, `option`. If you want something like that you can create it using `ul`, `li`. You can check my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/set-width-at-option-of-select-box/37601680#37601680