# Dynamically expand Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with several dropdowns with different lengths (widths).
I want the shorter dropdowns to have the same widths as the longer ones:

[image]

A quick solution is:

```
.mySel {
  width: 35%;
}
```

But, of course, this is not dynamically.

It there any way to dynamically define the widths of the shorter dropdowns, so that it expands over the entire table cell?
Maybe with jQuery?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stzbsvj6/1/).

Comment: Your html is having two select dropdowns with same id, you should never ever have same id to different element in same page, accept it and live happy life.

Comment: @rahul_m: Thanks, I've corrected that.

Comment: then anything will work. either css or jquery too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve that using flex box like this

```css
.flx{
  display:flex;
}

.flx select {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Text</td>
      <td>
      <div class="flx">
      
    
        From:
        <select id="mySel1">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        To:
        <select id="mySel2">
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
          <option>13</option>
        </select>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Text</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Option 4</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>A very loooong option</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601680/7490341
my suggestion is to maintain seperate `<td>` for each drop down and in css style follow the above link

Comment: Next time, whenever you will have answer related to question or same question asked before, please raise duplicate flag.