# How to fix size of option in select attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

Hello everyone here i am trying to fix the size of select and option attribute,by setting CSS properties to the select its fixed but after selecting the drop down list the size of options is changing,i have checked stackoverflow answers but they are also not working if we put lengthy text in option tag its changing the size of options tag.

here is what i am currently getting:

[image]

what i am expecting is here:

[image]

i just want to fix the size of select tag and option tag.
if anybudy know that how can we achive this Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

here is link what i have found on stackoverflow [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/set-width-at-option-of-select-box)

but its not working for me.

and here is my code where I am using select attribute:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding select-job">
    <label for="selectJob" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding"> Select Job </label>
    <select id="selectJob" name="selectJob" class="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start" ng-model="formInfo.selectedJob" ng-options="job.jobTitle for job in companyJob track by job.jobTitle">
     <option value="">Select your option</option>
     </select>
     <button class="btn btn-labeled btn-info btn-reload pull-right" ng-disabled="formInfo.selectedJob == undefined || formInfo.selectedJob == null" data-ng-click="uploadJobDescription()">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <span class="small-left-margin">Load Job</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle of what you are doing

Comment: in questions i have provided link you can go through it