# Vertical scrollbar hidden iin the selection box

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a problem in the selection box, I can't see the vertical scrollbar in the right-hand site, it makes me difficult to scroll down in the selection box to choose the option. Hope someone can guide me how to solve it.

```html
<style>
#parentid{
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  size:10;
}
</style>


<select onchange="getComboA(this)" class="form-control blank" id="parentid" name="parentid" title="parentid">
    <option value="please_select">--Sila Pilih--</option>
    <option value="0">New Category</option>
    <?php
    $sql_incharge = 'select * from filing_code_management where status=1 and is_approved = 1 and category_id in (1,2,3,4)ORDER BY id ASC';
    $arr_incharge = db_conn_select($sql_incharge);
    foreach ($arr_incharge as $rs_incharge) {
        $folder_location      = $rs_incharge['folder_location'];
        $function_code_select = $rs_incharge['function_code'];
        $function_name_select = $rs_incharge['function_name'];
        $activity_code_select = $rs_incharge['activity_code'];
        $activity_name_select = $rs_incharge['activity_name'];
        $name_select          = $rs_incharge['name'];
        $id_select            = $rs_incharge['id'];
        $root             = $rs_incharge['id_root'];
        $category_id          = $rs_incharge['category_id']; // get category_id here
        // save the data here↓↓ in data attributes 
        echo "<option value='{$id_select}' data-cat_id='{$category_id}' data-root='{$root}'>{$name_select}</option>";
        }
?></select>
```

[image: Scroll down problem]

I want the expected result like below the sample picture:

[image: Output 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you at least provide CSS and copy the html you are getting in your browser ? to test with similar data ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Updated CSS in my quesiton. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to change `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:scroll;`?

Comment: I have tried overflow:scroll;. the result is same

Comment: This is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/set-width-at-option-of-select-box   Just reduce the width how you want as in this question

Comment: @MaxiGui I've tried to use your link. But doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering more clearly but this answer has been posted [Set Width at Option of Select Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/set-width-at-option-of-select-box)

If needed, you can add a setTimeOut to be sure it is well applied

```js
$('option').each(function() {
  var optionText = this.text;
  var newOption = optionText.substring(0, 36);
  $(this).text(newOption + '...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<select style="width:250px">
    <option>Select your University</option>
    <option>Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology</option>
    <option>Mawlana Bhashani Science and Technology University</option>
</select>
```