# how to make html select options width fixed?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html-select

how to make width of select options fixed and give text break to lengthy options ? I tried adding max-width to options. But its not working.

```css
select{
max-width:100px !important;
}
select option{
max-width:100px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Hey this is the problem related to our CSS select option drop down. width is not working in options</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the width of select box options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-select-box-options)

Comment: @Zohini I was looking for a way without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> We use href="#" for test links. In a real web site this would be URLs.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry  I'm using a select tag